# Cache not updated in Azure devops Pipelines using Java Maven

Tags: java, maven, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a problem with Azure devops Pipeline using Java Maven and caching. When I change a file in a custom dependency then the Cache is not updated by Azure devops.

I use Azure devops artifacts to store the created artifacts.

I have a basic Java Application we call it:  nl.mycompany.toolA

I have a dependency with the name: nl.mycompany.dependencyB

The Dependency nl.mycompany.dependencyB is included via the pom.xml in the basic Java application

This is my Azure devops pipeline code:

```
# Maven
variables:
  MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.m2/repository
  MAVEN_OPTS: '-Dmaven.repo.local=$(MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER)'

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  name: settings_xml
  displayName: Download settings.xml
  inputs:
    secureFile: 'settings.xml'

- task: Cache@2
  inputs:
    key: 'maven | "$(Agent.OS)" | **/pom.xml'
    restoreKeys: |
      maven | "$(Agent.OS)"
      maven
    path: $(MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER)
  displayName: Cache Maven local repo

- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    goals: 'deploy'
    options: '-s $(settings_xml.secureFilePath)'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m $(MAVEN_OPTS)'
    mavenAuthenticateFeed: false
    effectivePomSkip: false
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
```

My dependency nl.mycompany.dependencyB  has a file: sharedModule/cdm.dwl which very often has to be updated.

First I build my basic Java app with Azure Devops pipeline, with the code above and the inserted Junit tests run fine.

Then I update the cdm.dwl file in the dependency
Then I build the dependency with Azure devops with the code above.

Then I build the basic Java app with Azure devops again and the Junit test run fine again but they should give an error because the cdm.dwl file has changed.

When I download the JAR file and check the content the included dependency does not have the updated cdm.dwl file, so the cache is NOT updated by Azure devops.

When I remove the Cache@2 task in the pipeline yaml file then there is no problem at all.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for this problem thanks to a coleague of mine:
Changes this line in the script above:

```
goals: 'deploy'
```

in this line:

```
goals: 'deploy -U'
```

Will do the job, because it forces Maven to Update the dependencies.